# Why is $\|y\|_1 = \lambda^{-1}\|x\|_1$ given that $y = \lambda - 1x$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Exercise:** Prove that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2\leq \|x\|_1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

*What I've tried:* I think I successfully proved the first inequality. For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, one has $\left|x_k\right|\leq \bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\left|x_j\right|^2\bigg)^{1/2} = \|x\|_2$. If we combine this with $\|x\|_\infty = \sup_n\left|x_n\right|$ we know that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2.$ I wasn't able to prove the second inequality, but I have the following solution:

> Let $\lambda = \|x\|_1$. Consider the vector $y = \lambda - 1x$. Then by the properties of a norm we obtain $\|y\|_1 = \lambda^{-1}\|x\|_1 = 1.$ Therefore, $\left|y_k\right|\leq 1$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. It follows that $\left|y_k\right|^2 \leq \left|y_k\right|$, and thus $$\|y\|_1^2\sum_{k=1}^n\left|y_k\right|^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\left|y_k\right| =\|y\|_1= 1$$ We can conclude that $\|y\|_2 \leq 1$. Since $x = \lambda y$, we obtain $$\|x\|_2 = \left|\lambda\right|\|y\|_2 \leq \left|\lambda\right| = \|x\|_1$$

**Question:** Why do we have that $\|y\|_1 = \lambda^{-1}\|x\|_1$ if $y = \lambda - 1x$? (I don't understand why there is a one before the $x$). I understand the rest of the solution except for the part "$x =\lambda y$".

Thanks!

Comment: What does "$y=\lambda -1x$" mean?

Comment: @5xum Sorry, edited!

Comment: You edited, but $y=\lambda - 1x$ is still there...

Comment: @5xum I know, this is the given solution! I don't understand why this is downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should read $y= \lambda^{-1}x$ and not $y = \lambda - 1x$. Then we have $\|y\|_1 = \lambda^{-1}\|x\|_1$ and $x= \lambda y$.